# Breaking from foreach loop

Tags: php, post, foreach

I'm working on a website wherein rows are generated depending on how many users there are. In this example, I have three users. Basically, I pass data through $_POST using drop down select data. Here's what I'm passing to PHP. These are wrapped in `<form>` but I cleaned it to show just the important data.

```
...
<select name="taction[3]" >
 <option value="accept">Accept</option>
<select name="taction[4]" >
 <option value="accept">Accept</option>
<select name="taction[6]" >
 <option value="accept">Accept</option>
...
```

My php looks like this:

```
$total = 1;
foreach ($_POST['taction'] as $userid => $action)
{
    if ($action == "accept")
    {
        if ($total<1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $userid."foo";
            $total = ($total - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, it is still displaying three "foo's" when it should've stopped after the first "foo". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you execute the whole code block (including the leading `$total = 1` three times?

Comment: one thing i noticed instantly in your code is => should be >= for "greater than or equal", rather than, equal or greater than"

Comment: Jimmy that => is for the foreach loop, not for checking a greater/equal than

Comment: ah was just skimmming quickly and it stuck out

Comment: @JimmyBanks no, that's one of the two forms of the foreach construct in PHP.

Comment: The code works fine with dummy data, your HTML is wrong... your selects are never closed... try var_dump($_POST) to see what gets in...

Comment: @Mike Sanchez looks like you aren't doing TDD. Why not give it a shot? You would probably fix the error in no time, and what's even more important, prevent it from happening ever again in the first place.

Comment: your code works fine on my computer. can you reproduce your problem with the code you posted, providing `$_POST["taction"] = array(1=>"accept",2=>"accept");`?

Comment: @s.m. there is nothing to do with TDD here... he just sends wrong data...

Comment: @Djumaka: well, if he had tests in place, he would know that the code works well with valid input instead of wasting time looking at the wrong spot, wouldn't he? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. I was at fault by relying on variables outside the foreach statement. I had to copy the operations inside the loop again for it to register the added data.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
if($total <= 1)
```

Or start the $total variable at 0.

Comment: then he won't get any output because the foreach loop will break on the first round even before printing any user.